# Where is the actual event handling code?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've gone all google-eyed and mush-brained trying to figure out wha this code is actually supposed to accomplish.

In some cases the following is called with a bool arg of true (as shown here), other times false:

```
InitializeBackgroundThread_PDALoginTerminate(true);
```

That InitializeBackgroundThread_PDALoginTerminate() method connects or disconnects event handlers, it seems:

```
private void InitializeBackgroundThread_PDALoginTerminate( bool add )
{
    try
    {
        if ( add ) 
            pc.PDALoginTerminate += new PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler( DeinitLoginDialogs );
        else
            pc.PDALoginTerminate -= new PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler( DeinitLoginDialogs );
```

. . .

...and this is the code that PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler() points to:

```
public   delegate  void  PDALoginTerminateEventHandler();
public   event           PDALoginTerminateEventHandler PDALoginTerminate;
public   void          OnPDALoginTerminate()
{
    if (PDALoginTerminate != null)
        PDALoginTerminate();
}
```

I don't see what's going on here, if anything is really happening at all; it seems as if the code is just chasing its own tail around or is one big wild goose chase/circular reference; right-clicking PDALoginTerminate() takes me to the line above it.

What am I missing (besides, hopefully temporarily, a good bit of my sanity)?

NOTE: This is a .NET 1.1 project.

### UPDATE

I like the simplification idea, but if I do this:

```
pc.PDALoginTerminate += DeinitLoginDialogs;
```

...I get, "*Method 'PDAClient.frmCentral.DeinitLoginDialogs()' referenced without parentheses*"

...and if I do this:

```
pc.PDALoginTerminate += DeinitLoginDialogs();
```

I get, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler'*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the handler:

```
DeinitLoginDialogs
```

You're going back to the method which *raises* the event, but the handler is assigned (or unassigned) here:

```
if ( add ) 
    pc.PDALoginTerminate += new PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler( DeinitLoginDialogs );
else
    pc.PDALoginTerminate -= new PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler( DeinitLoginDialogs );
```

Note the argument to the `PDALoginTerminateEventHandler` constructor.  It's worth noting that the conversion can be performed implicitly, i.e., this nastiness:

```
pc.PDALoginTerminate += new PendingCommands.PDALoginTerminateEventHandler( DeinitLoginDialogs );
```

Becomes...

```
pc.PDALoginTerminate += DeinitLoginDialogs;
```

Yay.  The long names don't help readability here unfortunately.  They hurt my head too.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Are you using C# 1.0?  That feature came about in 2.0.

Comment: I don't know the C# version, but it's a Windows CE/Compact Framework .NET 1.1 project. I updated my post and tags accordingly; sorry about that.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Yeah that's why, it's a very old version.  Just stick with the verbose syntax for now, you can't use the more concise version.  There's no semantic difference.